# The subset $I$ of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ consisting of polynomials vanishing at $1,2,$ and $3$ is a principal ideal.

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

I am asked to show that the subset $I$ of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ consisting of polynomials vanishing at $1,2,$ and $3$ is a principal ideal.

This question is a little trickier for me than most because I don't have $F[x]$ where $F$ is field:

***Proposition 17.** If the polynomial $f(x)$ has roots $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_k$ in $F$ (not necessarily distinct), then $f(x)$ has $(x-\alpha_1)\cdots (x-\alpha_k)$ as a factor. In particular, a polynomial of degree $n$ in one variable over a field $F$ has at most $n$ roots in $F$, even counted with multiplicity.*

is Proposition 17(Sec 9.5) from Dummit & Foote.

I had an earlier exercise that asked to prove that $I$ was an ideal,

Let $p(x)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, then $p(x) \in I \not= \{\}=\varnothing$

Say one had two polynomials in $f(x),g(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ vanishing at $1,2,$ and $3$, then let $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$. $h(1)=h(2)=h(3)=0$ because $f,g$ vanish at $1,2,3$. And $h(x) \in I$, $I$ is closed under subtraction.

If one took any polynomial $P(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, then $P(x)f(x), f(x)P(x)\in I$ and $I$ is closed under left and right multiplication by any element of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and must be closed under multiplication in particular. This concludes that $I$ is a subring, and furthermore, that $I$ is an two-sided ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

I think it is easy to see that $\left(p(x)\right) \subset \mathbb{Z}[x]$.

I did learn a Division Algorithm for monic polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ which shows that given $f(x)\in I$, then $(x-1),(x-2),(x-3)$ must be factors of $f(x)$ but how do I piece them all together to show that $p(x)|f(x)$?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a UFD and $x-1$, $x-2$, $x-3$ are relatively prime.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, my argument may be overkill: $x-2,x-3$ are irreducible by Eisenstein's Criterion, and $(x-1)-1=x-2$ is irreducible by Eisenstein, and thus $x-1$ must be irreducible, for if there were a factorization of $x-1$ then we'd have a factorization of $x-2$ by replacing $x$ by $x-1$. $x-1,x-2,x-3$ are all irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and thus by UFD, since the only units in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ are namely those in $\mathbb{Z}^*=\{\pm 1\}$ every factorization is of the form $\pm 1(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)g(x)$? That is the best I can do... I had to avoid relatively prime, sorry

Comment: They are irreducible because they are degree 1 and monic. Invoking Eisenstein is indeed terrible overkill.

Comment: What? All you need is that the degree of a product is the sum of the degrees. So if $p(x)q(x) = x-a$, then one of $p(x)$, $q(x)$ is constant and the other is degree $1$. And because the product is monic, the only possible constants are $1$ and $-1$. What do you mean you “don’t have access to that yet”? It’s **extremely** basic. Certainly more so than Eisenstein’s criterion!

Comment: @ArturoMagidin would you have a book recommendation for Ring Theory then? One where they cover Number Fields as well?

Comment: This has nothing to do with number fields. The study of number fields is best left to algebraic number theory; general ring theory has too much to cover to busy itself with number fields.

Comment: "Quadratic integer rings" what? Finish D&F or any other basic abstract algebra book first, before trying to jump to more advanced books. They will all assume mastery of the basic concepts, which is clearly something you are still struggling with.

Comment: I have read D&F, I'm sure you know you can find Quadratic Integer Rings on page 229 D&F, and don't worry about me, can you please answer my question? If not, have a good day

Comment: Your prior comment has a sentence fragment; I don't read minds. If you can't say what you mean, then don't complain when people are unable to give you what you want but won't say, and go have your own good day. If you want to learn about number fields, then read "Number Fields" by Marcus.

Comment: The Proposition 17 cited by the OP remains valid (counting multiplcities) when $F$ is any integral domain, since the division algorithm is valid for monic polynomials over any commutative ring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** Since $D(X)=(X-1)(X-2)(X-3)$ is monic, we can appply the division algorithm. Therefore, if $f \in I$ then in $\mathbb Z[X]$ we have
$$
f(X)=(X-1)(X-2)(X-3)Q(X)+aX^2+bX+c \,.
$$
for some $Q(X) \in \mathbb Z[X]$. Now, use $f(1)=f(2)=f(3)=0$ to conclude that $a=b=c=0$.

Comment: I really appreciate this answer, thank you

Comment: Thank you for reducing it to the linear independence of the column vectors of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1& 1& 1\\4&2&1\\9&3&1 \end{pmatrix}$, this is probably one of my favorite $3\times 3$ matrices, and I know its RREF is the identity from working out examples in the past!

Comment: @nolemonnomelon This is a particular case of a vandermonde matrix see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix

Comment: @nolemonnomelon Note that you can also use polynomials to finish the problem instead of linear indepence of the columns of the matrix. Indeed if $R(X)=aX^2+bX+c$ the $R(1)=R(2)=R(3)=0$ and hence $R$ is a polymial of degree at most 2 in $\mathbb Q[X]$ with $3$ roots.